# Editing and removing value in json using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this JSON,

```
{"items":[{"Code":"c101","Desc":"Car"},{"Code":"c341","Desc":"House"}]}
```

How can I edit the Desc of the item that have a code of c341?
How can I delete the item that have a code of c101?

I tried this code but not working,

```
delete obj.items.Code="c101"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deleting the item with specific id use [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice),

```
obj.items.splice(obj.items.findIndex(v => v.Code == "c101"), 1)
```

For editing use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find),

```
var edit = obj.items.find(v => v.Code == "c341")
edit.Code = "asd" //This will affect the item's code in the original array
                  //since `find()` will return the reference not a copy.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more efficient solutions out there, but this is the basic idea of what you want to do.

```
$.each(obj.items, function (index, element){
  if (element.Code === "c101") {
    obj.items.splice(index, 1);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you have to find the item by its code and then edit it

```
var obj = {"items":[{"Code":"c101","Desc":"Car"},{"Code":"c341","Desc":"House"}]};

function getItemByCode(code){

    for(var i in obj.items){
        var item = obj.items[i];
        if(item.Code === code){
            return item;
        };
    };
}

var item = getItemByCode('c341');    

item.Desc = "new desc"
```

This solution works with IE9+ and others browsers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```js
var json_string = '{"items":[{"Code":"c101","Desc":"Car"},{"Code":"c341","Desc":"House"}]}';
var json = JSON.parse(json_string);

if (json && json.items) {
 json.items = json.items.filter((element, i) => {
  if (element.Code) {
   return element.Code != 'c101';
  }
  return true;
 });
}
```